# create a pop up to print the product page in magento

Tags: product, print, popup

i have a example of what i exactly want, on a magento website
http://www.strollers.ro/
on a product page, we have a link(first print button), which redirect to the same page in a pop up, with a print button.

My question , because i spent a week trying to achieve this.
which file should i edit?

There seems to be some files for PDF or pop up in Magento folders, do I need to create a module?

All I want is a link to a `phtml` file (`print.phtml`? is this the file?) that represent the same page without sidebar, footer etc, and with just product description and a print button.

I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

There is a rule to add `skin/frontend/package/theme/css/print.css`. If the file exists in your theme it will automatically be added in your frontend.

You could add this file and edit accordingly for print specific styles.

Add a button on your productpage with window.print() as action and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

There's a **FREE Magento Extension** for this: [Print Product & Shopping Cart Page](https://marketplace.magento.com/chapagain-chapagain-clearprint.html)

Comment: What about magento 2 for Print Product Page ?